# AngularJS Modal Closing, with button into Form, cause redirect

Tags: angularjs, forms, modal-dialog

i have one page (.aspsx) open by angularjs modal, this is the code:

```
<form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" runat="server">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div style="float: left; display: block;">
                <h3 class="modal-title">{{vmc.title}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div style="float: right; display: block;">
                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn btn-success" runat="server" ID="btnCreaUser" OnClick="btnCreaUser_Click" Text="Save" />
                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-ng-click="vmc.close()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
```

When the "Cancel" button is clicked, call the method in the controller:

```
   function close() {
        var type = "cancel";
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss({ type: type, result: null });
    }
```

The page is closed correctly, but after the close there is a redirect to the modal page (with incorrect path, only the page name) and i have an error.

How can i prevent the redirect?

thanks

**UPDATE**
With the type="button" attribute, the "Cancel" button works correctly.

But now i've notice that the asp:button has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `button` default type is submit, which submits the form. Use `type="button"` attribute:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" data-ng-click="vmc.close()" type="button">Cancel</button>
```

[Read the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: Thank you very much, now work perfectly....E.C.:the "Cancel" works, but the "Save" has the same problem.,....

Comment: There is [UseSubmitBehaviur](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.80).aspx) attribute. So: `<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn btn-success" runat="server" ID="btnCreaUser" OnClick="btnCreaUser_Click" Text="Save" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />` will add `type="button"` to the button and it should work as you wish.