# How to close only textbox using cancel button(HTML,BootStrap,AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I have editable table with EDIT button at bottom of 1 column, after clicking on EDIT , column becomes editable and 2 buttons(SAVE and CANCEL) will open.**On click of CANCEL,I want to make that column NON EDITABLE as it was before.**

HTML CODE:

```
<tr>
<td>
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-hide="editingData[row.scenarioName]"
        ng-click="modify(row)">Edit</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-show="editingData[row.scenarioName]"
        ng-click="update(row);initFunction();"
        style="background-color: #37918f; border-color: #37918f;"
        ng-disabled="!isNumberValid">Save
</button>  
<button class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

Sorry  I am unable to paste the photo because of points.

Comment: [Possible answer that may be your solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35866732/9756630) The button having a basic 'submit' default.

Comment: though I have pasted same JS code then also it is not wokring

Comment: If you have some buggy code, post it. It’s really hard to answer a question about a bug in code when the question doesn’t include any of the buggy code.

Comment: Noted @georgeawg

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the click of cancel button:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="showTextBoxes=false">Cancel</button>
```

Let your two textboxes be:

```
<input id="textbox1" type="text" ng-if="showTextBoxes"/>
<input id="textbox2" type="text" ng-if="showTextBoxes"/>
```

Don't forget to declare the boolean variable `showTextBoxes=false;` in your javascript/typescript!

Comment: It will disappear my textboxes, after clicking on EDIT my textboxes come otherwise it is like table data.

Comment: Can you be a little bit clearer?.Let me assume your stuff.On clicking edit button two textboxes are shown and on clicking cancel both the buttons should be hidden?Correct?

Comment: No.On clicking edit button -> table column become editable(column becomes editable textboxes) and 2 buttons will appear SAVE and CANCEL.SAVE button is working fine but on CANCEL it should become normal column . Please let me know whether you get my scenario or not.

Comment: On that case try using ng-disabled instead of ng-if

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="isClosed = true">Cancel</button>
```

and in your Textboxes

```
<input id="textbox1" type="text" ng-disabled="isClosed"/>
<input id="textbox1" type="text" ng-disabled="isClosed"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.Thanks Joe, I got hint from your answer.I need to put

```
ng-click="open = false"
```

and

```
ng-if="!open" in <span> having my data
```